# How to display stock information on product page?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, stock, stock-status

I would like to display the stock status *(In Stock | Sold Out)* on the product page.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To display the "out of stock" and "in stock" label on product view page, write the below code in the file `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

```
<?php    
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
    $qty = $stock->getQty();
    if($qty <= 0)
    {
?>
       <span class="out-of-stock"><span>Sold Out</span></span>
<?php
    }
    else
    {
?>
       <span class="in-stock"><span>In stock</span></span>
<?php
    }
?>
```

And if you want the label on the category page, write in `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

**NOTE** : It is assumed that you are using magento-1.9 or greater

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the quick response! I forgot to mention, I am using custom theme boilerplate, do I still edit the files you mentioned or use the ones from my theme?

Comment: no, in this case you need to edit the file from your theme

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 5):

you can check product is in stock  via below code

```
$stockItem = $product->getStockItem();
if ($stockItem->getIsInStock()) {
    //in stock!
} else {
    //not in stock!
}
```

Comment: app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

Answer (score 2):

Get the stock details in magento  using below lines.

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
           ->loadByProduct($productId);
         print_r($stockItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rwd theme, you can find the code to show product stock availability at

> app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view\type\availability\default.phtml

Comment: Hi! I am using custom bolierplate theme, I presume it will be the same location but under my custom theme?

Comment: Simple, You can refer to how to do it in rwd theme

Comment: Good shout, I check that!

Comment: Wish you success!